# Trying to make a 4 colored circle rotate with a button in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create a circle that displays four colors where each quarter of the wheel has a distinct color and has a button that is used to rotate the colors of the wheel 90 degrees to the right when pressed.

This is the code that I have so far. I have the button and circle showing up fine but can't get it to rotate when the button is pressed.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
import javafx.scene.shape.ArcType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class four_color_wheel extends Application {
    private Group circle;
    private FlowPane pane;
    private Button rotate;
    private Arc blueArc, greenArc, yellowArc, redArc;



    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    

        // Blue Arc
        Arc blueArc = new Arc(200, 200, 150, 150, 0, 90);
        blueArc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
        blueArc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        blueArc.setFill(Color.BLUE);
    
        // Green Arc
        Arc greenArc = new Arc(200, 200, 150, 150, 90, 90);
        greenArc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
        greenArc.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
        greenArc.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    
        // Yellow Arc
        Arc yellowArc = new Arc(200, 200, 150, 150, 180, 90);
        yellowArc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
        yellowArc.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);
        yellowArc.setFill(Color.YELLOW);

        // Red Arc
        Arc redArc = new Arc(200, 200, 150, 150, 270, 90);
        redArc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
        redArc.setStroke(Color.RED);
        redArc.setFill(Color.RED);

        Group circle = new Group(blueArc, greenArc, yellowArc, redArc);

        Button rotate = new Button("Rotate Right");
        rotate.setOnAction(this::processButtonPress);
    
        FlowPane pane = new FlowPane(circle, rotate);
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        pane.setHgap(20);
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: GRAY");
    
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 100);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Four-Color Wheel");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
     
    
    
    } 
    
    
 public void processButtonPress(ActionEvent event)
    {
        Group circle = new Group(blueArc, greenArc, yellowArc, redArc);
        circle.setRotate(90);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're creating a new `Group` and rotating it, instead of rotating the existing `Group`.

Comment: I would also expect this code to throw a `NullPointerException`. You have fields that a referenced in `processButtonPress`, but those fields are never initialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- many local variables are hidding fields

2- please , stay with java naming convention

3- if you want to rotate something you need to add its current rotation to the angle

```
public class FourColorWheel extends Application {

private Group circle;
private FlowPane pane;
private Button rotate;
private Arc blueArc, greenArc, yellowArc, redArc;

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    // Blue Arc
    blueArc = new Arc(200, 200, 150, 150, 0, 90);
    blueArc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
    blueArc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    blueArc.setFill(Color.BLUE);

    // Green Arc
    greenArc = new Arc(200, 200, 150, 150, 90, 90);
    greenArc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
    greenArc.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
    greenArc.setFill(Color.GREEN);

    // Yellow Arc
    yellowArc = new Arc(200, 200, 150, 150, 180, 90);
    yellowArc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
    yellowArc.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);
    yellowArc.setFill(Color.YELLOW);

    // Red Arc
    redArc = new Arc(200, 200, 150, 150, 270, 90);
    redArc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
    redArc.setStroke(Color.RED);
    redArc.setFill(Color.RED);

    circle = new Group(blueArc, greenArc, yellowArc, redArc);

    rotate = new Button("Rotate Right");
    rotate.setOnAction(this::processButtonPress);

    pane = new FlowPane(circle, rotate);
    pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    pane.setHgap(20);
    pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: GRAY");

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 400);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Four-Color Wheel");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}

public void processButtonPress(ActionEvent event) {

    circle.setRotate(circle.getRotate() + 90);
}
}
```

Result :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want the circle to behave more like a wheel, replace the button handler with the following.

```
    public void processButtonPress(ActionEvent event) {
        ((Button) event.getSource()).setDisable(true);
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(60), actionEvent -> circle.setRotate(circle.getRotate() + 1)));
        timeline.setCycleCount(90);
        timeline.setOnFinished((onFinishEvent) -> {
            ((Button) event.getSource()).setDisable(false);
        });
        timeline.play();
    }
```

---

**Adding @Slaw implementation.**

```
    public void processButtonPress(ActionEvent event) {
        ((Button) event.getSource()).setDisable(true);
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new KeyValue(circle.rotateProperty(), circle.getRotate() + 90)));
        timeline.setOnFinished((onFinishEvent) -> {
            ((Button) event.getSource()).setDisable(false);
        });
        timeline.play();
    }
```

---

[image]

Comment: Note you can also do this with a `RotateTransition` and a call to `setByAngle(90)`. Might be smoother.

Comment: And actually, if you're going to use `Timeline` like this, it would be better to have a single-cycle animation with a `KeyValue` in the frame. For instance, something like `new KeyFrame(duration, new KeyValue(circle.rotateProperty(), circle.getRotate() + 90))`. Though I personally would still prefer `RotateTransition` in this case.

Comment: @Slaw. Good stuff! I did not know it can be done that way!

Answer (score 4):

***Preface:** The other answers already solve your problem, but I thought I'd add some explanation.*

---

## Problems

There are a few problems with your code, all discussed below.

### Uninitialized Fields

The most immediate problem is the following error when you run the program and press the button.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Children: child node is null: parent = Group@2a18a4be
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$3.onProposedChange(Parent.java:543)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.addAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:233)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.addAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:103)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Group.<init>(Group.java:106)
        at four_color_wheel.processButtonPress(four_color_wheel.java:76)
        ...
```

This is thrown in this method:

```java
public void processButtonPress(ActionEvent event) {
    Group circle = new Group(blueArc, greenArc, yellowArc, redArc);
    circle.setRotate(90);
}
```

Because `blueArc`, `greenArc`, `yellowArc`, and `redArc` are all null. A parent in JavaFX cannot have null children.

Your class has fields that you never initialize. Instead, you create local variables with the same name in the `start` method. Those local variables hide/shadow the fields in the context of the `start` method. But the `processButtonPress` method is referencing the fields (because the local variables of the `start` method are out of scope). To fix this, simply initialize the fields instead of creating local variables.

For example, instead of:

```java
// Blue Arc
Arc blueArc = new Arc(200, 200, 150, 150, 0, 90);
blueArc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
blueArc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
blueArc.setFill(Color.BLUE);
```

Do:

```java
// Blue Arc
blueArc = new Arc(200, 200, 150, 150, 0, 90);
blueArc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
blueArc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
blueArc.setFill(Color.BLUE);
```

By not having the type in front of the `blueArc = ...` you are assigning the field instead of creating a local variable. Do the same for all your fields.

### Rotating the Wrong Group

This method:

```java
public void processButtonPress(ActionEvent event) {
    Group circle = new Group(blueArc, greenArc, yellowArc, redArc);
    circle.setRotate(90);
}
```

Is creating a new `Group`. This causes two issues:

1. You are rotating a `Group` that is not being displayed in the UI. Thus, the rotation has no visible effect.
2. A node in JavaFX cannot belong to two parents. By creating a new `Group` and adding the arcs to it, those arcs are implicitly removed from their current `Group` first. This will remove the arcs from the displayed UI.

The fix is to reference the field `circle` instead of creating a new `Group`.

```java
public void processButtonPress(ActionEvent event) {
    circle.setRotate(90);
}
```

The above assumes you've initialized the `circle` field as discussed in the previous section.

### You Set the Rotation to a Constant

I assume you want the "circle" to rotate **by** 90 degrees every time you press the button. To do this, you need to *add* 90 degrees to the *current* rotation.

```java
circle.setRotation(circle.getRotation() + 90);
```

Otherwise, with your current code, the circle will rotate **to** 90 degrees upon the first button press, and then will never rotate again.

### No Animation

This is not a problem *per se*. However, it is typically good to use animations for this sort of thing. It lets the user see the results of their actions clearly and can also help direct the user's attention. You can use a `Timeline` to implement the animation, but in this case it would probably be cleaner to use a `RotateTransition`. See the example at the end of this answer for more information.

### Not Following Standard Naming Conventions

You should always follow the naming and formatting conventions of your team or organization (or, if you're working alone, the conventions you choose--just be consistent). But when posting code on a public forum like Stack Overflow, you should follow the *standard* naming and formatting conventions of the programming language. In Java, class names should follow `PascalCase`, also known as `UpperCamelCase`.

In other words, your class should be named:

```java
public class FourColorWheel extends Application {
   ...
}
```

---

## Example

Here's your code with fixes for the problems discussed above. There were also some other modifications made to make the code cleaner, including:

- Generalizing the creation of a multi-colored "circle", allowing a circle with any number of colors to be made.
- Only keeping fields that were absolutely needed (because those objects needed to be referenced between methods). It's typically a good idea to keep things as narrowly scoped as possible when programming.
- Using an `HBox` instead of a `FlowPane` to give a better initial layout. This change was only for the example; using a `FlowPane` is not wrong (assuming it's the right layout for your real program).
- Disabling the button while the animation is running so it can't accidentally be restarted in the middle of a rotation.

Here's the code:

```java
import javafx.animation.RotateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
import javafx.scene.shape.ArcType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import static javafx.animation.Animation.Status.RUNNING;

public class FourColorWheel extends Application {

    private RotateTransition animation;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group circle = createMultiColorCircle(Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Color.RED);

        animation = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(175), circle);
        animation.setByAngle(90);

        Button rotate = new Button("Rotate Right");
        rotate.disableProperty().bind(animation.statusProperty().isEqualTo(RUNNING));
        rotate.setOnAction(this::handleButtonPress);
    
        HBox pane = new HBox(20, circle, rotate);
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(20));
    
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Four-Color Wheel");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void handleButtonPress(ActionEvent event) {
        event.consume();
        animation.playFromStart();
    }

    private Group createMultiColorCircle(Color... colors) {
        Group circle = new Group();

        double startAngle = 0.0;
        double length = 360.0 / colors.length;
        for (Color color : colors) {
            Arc arc = new Arc(200, 200, 150, 150, startAngle, length);
            arc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
            arc.setStroke(color);
            arc.setFill(color);
            circle.getChildren().add(arc);

            startAngle += length;
        }

        return circle;
    }
}
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]